# Add commons-io dependency to gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio

Very simple question - how to add *commons-io* dependency to gradle Android project?

I tried the following

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'
}
```

but it does not work 
The error is

Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':LearnIt'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':LearnIt:_DebugCompile'.
>         **> Could not find commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1.**
>           Required by:
>               learnit:LearnIt:unspecified

Comment: In case anyone needs all apache commons libs - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you need to declare a repository where you want to resolve the commons-io library from (e.g. MavenCentral):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: see buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

Comment: You have it configured inside `buildScript`, but not inside the build file itself. `buildScript` is used to declare additional dependencies needed by the custom tasks themselves, and not dependencies needed by the project being built. Also note that Rene is a gradle committer. He knows what he's talking about. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_dependencies

Comment: ok thank you! Now it is clear, but was a little bit confusing at the beginning

Comment: I am keep getting this error : Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils'. Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Something like this would work these days as well: implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

Answer (score 80):

As of now (May 2014) if you use the default generated project it is actually amazingly simple (though difficult to find instructions!

Open the *second level* build.gradle, and add the following line to the `dependencies {`:

```
compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
```

That will get the latest version of `commons-io`. My complete file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
}
```

Comment: That works great - very useful to have IOUtils as part of the project.

Comment: Thanks for this but do not use + operator in dependencies. that is bad for version differences.

Comment: It has pros and cons.

Comment: @OmerKarakose is right. It is better to stick to one version and not pull the latest always.

Comment: @Timmmm  From where did u find it?

Answer (score 48):

Use [gradlePlease](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) to get the dependency.

Add the following to your app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

//**UPDATED**

```
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

Comment: for a jar download -> https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: This did for me: compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'  - for jcentre() repo.

Comment: @Sam From where did u find it?

Answer (score 9):

Update 2020 using gradle

```
// Home Page : https://commons.apache.org/

// IO - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'

// String / Text 
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.8'
```