# Cannot resolve symbol 'IOUtils'

Tags: java, android, apache, import, android-studio

I have used the following code to create a temporary file in my android app:

```
public File streamToFile (InputStream in) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("sample", ".tmp");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    return tempFile;
}
```

Now the problem is `Cannot resolve symbol 'IOUtils'`. I did a little bit of googling and discovered that for  using IOUtils I need to download and include a jar file. I downloaded the jar file from **[here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)**([commons-io-2.4-bin.zip](http://www.poolsaboveground.com/apache//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip)). I added the jar named `commons-io-2.4.jar` from the zip to my bundle and when I tried to import it using:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

It is showing error `Cannot resolve symbol 'io'`. So I tried to import it like:

```
import org.apache.commons.*
```

But still I am getting the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'IOUtils'`.

Question 1 : Why am I getting this error? How to resolve it?

Question 2 : Is there any way to create a temp file from an InputStream without using an external library? Or is this the most efficient way to do that? I am using android studio.

Comment: [How to add Gson dependency to your Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149777/2396539)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right clicking on the `commons-io-2.4.jar` file in project navigator and clicking 'Add to project' solved the issue.

Comment: @Zindarod late answer I know but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895557/add-commons-io-dependency-to-gradle-project-in-android-studio#comment61025941_33820307 for obtaining jar

Answer (score 102):

For Android Studio:

1. File -> Project Structure... -> Dependencies
2. Click '+' in the upper right corner and select "Library dependency"
3. In the search field type: "org.apache.commons.io" and click Search
4. Select "org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:<X.X>

**Or**

Add `implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4` to the `build.gradle` file

Comment: Or add `compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'` to the `build.gradle` file

Comment: To see the Dependices tab, first click on "app" under "Modules".

Comment: sometimes android studio doesn't install the dependencies if we do as in the answer.
its better to do it manually like @JoaquinIurchuk said

Answer (score 5):

Adding below dependency solved issue

```
 implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who encountered this while working on a Netbeans Java project. What I did is I downloaded the Binaries Zip of IO here

[Commons IO Util Jar Download Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)

Then Right clicked on my Project>Properties>

---

On the Categories Pane, Click Libraries

---

Then Click Add Jar/Folder

---

Locate the jar file/folder of the extracted IO Util that was downloaded.

---

Then click Ok. That fixed mine. :)

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:android-studio] an answer about Netbeans doesn't answer it.

Comment: android  uses close to java syntax anyway.& I was searching for this exact problem that I encountered while working in netbeans that used to be an IDE for developing in android,seems to be worth pointing out. The Step by step problems and necessary jar files provided above for android-studio is close to what will solve the same problem above if encountered in Netbeans. I'm just providing my version of it in netbeans since this could be encountered while working in netbeans too. 

Fact is, I am working on this java proj.in netbeans so that I could deploy it in android later with working code.

Answer (score 0):

First I added this dependency but got an error when installing the app on the device:

```
implementation("org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4")
```

Error:

```
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
```

Then based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54548820/8551764), I used this other dependency in my `build.gradle.kts` file and it worked:

```
implementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.5")
```