# Convert InputStream to base64 string

Tags: java, string, base64, inputstream

There is a way to convert an `InputStream` to a `String`, and encode it to base64, right?

In my function, I get `InputStream` parameter, and need to insert it into the BLOB field in my Oracle database table.

Is there a way to do that?

(My database object contains string field to save the image, but I don't find any way to convert the `InputStream` to string in base 64 format.)

Comment: Did you try anything at all? If your InputStream contains image data, don't use a ``String`` though, use ``byte[]``.

Comment: Ok, what is it mean? I need to change this field to Byte[]? and how can I convert it to Byte[] from inputStream? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for solution without external libraries. Java8 adds [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) utility class which contains `getEncoder()` method. Java9 adds fancy method on `InputStream` called `readAllBytes()` [Link to api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--)

So now you without any external libraries your code may look like

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

public String encode(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
  final var bytes = stream.readAllBytes();

  return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 33):

There is nice way to do this is using  [`IOUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to convert the InputStream into a `Byte Array`...

**something like**

```
    InputStream is;
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Here you can use `Base64` to convert `Byte Array` to `String`.

**Sample Code**

```
    String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Now you can use your `String`.

Comment: `IOUtils` is not found, consult this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578243/cannot-resolve-symbol-ioutils

Answer (score 30):

You can try something like this using the Base64 API.

```
InputStream finput = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
finput.read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
finput.close();
String imageStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Use this:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: new FileInputStream need to get file - I don't have file name.... I need to set inputStream....

Comment: that should be ok as long as you have InputStream with you . you use the mentioned logic

Comment: Base64.DEFAULT - get compilation error- DEFAULT is not field. what shuld I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from apache-commons to do that:

```
String result= IOUtils.toString(inputStream, ENCODING);
```

From the documentation:

> toString(byte[] input, String encoding)
>   Gets the contents of a byte[] as a String using the specified character encoding.

After that To Encode/Decode in Base64:

```
// Encode 
String resultBase64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result.getBytes("utf-8"));


// Decode
byte[] asBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(resultBase64Encoded);
String resultAsStringAgain= String(asBytes, "utf-8")
```

**Note:** I'm assuming you use JDK 8 for the Encode/Decode part.

Apparently the OP wants just to persist an InputStream to the DB. You can do that directly using JDBC:

```
InputStream inputStream = ......;
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_NAME) values (?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setBlob(1, inputStream);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @f1sh I know that but this is what the the OP asked for.

Comment: so what can I do? where do I put the image data before insert it to DB blob?

Comment: @foo If all you want to do is to save an InputStream into the DB you can do it directly without transforming it to anything else...

Comment: @foo  see me updated answer about How to persist an InputStream as Blob directly to the DB

Comment: To mee this is much more memory efficient way to do it, the byte[] in the accepted answer will eat it. You dont need a temp space to persist a stream.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, you shouldn't use `String` for binary data. The base64-encoded data can be stored as a String though. But since your database column is a blob, I would continue to work with a `byte[]`.

Use IOUtils to get a `byte[]` from the `InputStream`:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(yourInputStream);
byte[] encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
```

Then write it to the database. Writing a blob using jdbc and a PreparedStatement looks like this:

```
yourPreparedStatement.setBytes(nIndex, encoded);
```

Comment: which import I need to add?