# How to download XLSX file with Java Spring/React?

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, xlsx

I am attempting to generate an `.XLSX` file and download it. I am using `Apache POI` to generate the excel file and I am using `Swagger UI` to test the endpoint. I have been searching for a few hours with little luck. The code I am using to generate my Excel file is:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/download")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> download(@RequestParam(name = "ids") long [] ids) {
    // ... other code ...
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = createWorkbook(reports);

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

    String filename = "MYC " + date.getYear() + "." + date.getMonthValue();

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
        header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, String.format("attachment; filename=%s.xlsx", filename));
        workbook.write(stream);
        workbook.close();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(stream.toByteArray()), header, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

When testing with `Swagger UI`, I make the call and I get this in return:
[image]

An answer I found on SO advised using `force-download` instead of `vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` so I went ahead and gave it a try. This time, `Swagger UI` was actually generating a `Download file` link. I can click it and the file would download just fine. But is using `force-download` really an appropriate method?

Now, I attempted to download on my front-end and no matter if I am using `force-download` or `vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, I just get a 'corrupted' `.xlsx` file.

Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938925/download-an-xlsx-file-with-reactjs-excel-can-not-open-file) SO question while writing my own, and this person seems to also receive the same type of response. He fixed it by converting his binary data to string. Not sure if that is what I should do as well and how I would go about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to figure it out by gathering information from multiple google searches. For my backend, I encoded `byte array` to `Base64`, then returned it as a `String`.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/download")
public ResponseEntity<String> download(@RequestParam(name = "ids") long[] ids) {
    // ... other code ...
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = createWorkbook(reports);

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType("text", "plain");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

On the frontend, I decoded the `String` using [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob), then to `ArrayBuffer`

```
// ... other code ...
actions.getSpreadsheet(ids)
    .then(result => {
        var date = new Date();
        var filename = "JSC " +
            date.getFullYear() +
            "." +
            (date.getMonth() + 1);

        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.s2ab(atob(result.data))], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;' }));
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename + '.xlsx';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
    }).catch(error => {
        alert('Error retrieving report: ' + error);
    })

s2ab = s => {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    var view = new Unit8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i != s.length; i++) {
        view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to sort things out for streams. You are not even able to gather bytes from outputstream.