# Error while installing apk in the android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have tried all the possible solution available on stackoverflow. But I am getting the same error again and again. Not sure from where it's coming from.
I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414219/install-failed-no-matching-abis-failed-to-extract-native-libraries-res-113). And updated the build.gradle file to

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Till yesterday night this was working fine. But today it's ruining my day. Could some one please help me with this ?

I am not using additional application like genymotion or arc welder. I am getting this error on android emulator.

I tried running it on real device, but same issue.

Regards

Comment: What is your emulator's ABI?

Comment: It's x86_64, API 28

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_NO\_MATCHING\_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)

Comment: @Lokesh `x86_64`... Then do you have put any, for example, only `armeabi-v7a` specific lib inside `jniLibs`?

Comment: @GenoChen there was one but i deleted that.

Comment: @Lokesh After that, rebuild again?

Comment: @GenoChen Yea I tried that one as well. But no help

Comment: @GenoChen I found a fix for that. I have written an answer for that as well below. But didn't understand how the apache library could interfere the emulator performance. Do you have any idea ? please help me to understand this.

Comment: @KishoreJethava  I found a fix for that. I have written an answer for that as well below. But didn't understand how the apache library could interfere the emulator performance. Do you have any idea ? please help me to understand this.

Comment: @Lokesh Is adding that dependency reproducing the problem?

Comment: @GenoChen Yes I added that dependency and then struggling starts, I change the dependency name and problem fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Can't believe this error happened because of an apache library. I recently added few apache dependency in my project and then this error starts appearing. The line I added
`implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'`
And then after that struggling entire day. Finally I undo all my changes and find out this was happening because of the apache package.

I added this dependency in build.gradle and it works fine.
`implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'`.

But not able to figured out how the apache packages interrupt emulator to work properly. Strange !

Posting this answer so that if someone could understand the reason behind the problem, please explain it to me as well :P

Comment: Argh, just lost an hour or so to a halfway-meaningless Android Studio error which fixed itself when I made the same changes. Thanks for your note on it. My case was related to an Amazon Fire HD 10 tablet, and this 2.4 library version for some boilerplate I/O routine.