# Get image name from selected image in gallery

Tags: android

At the moment I am selecting an image from gallery and the whole path is shown example (/storage/emulated.0/DCIM/Camera/123.jpg) in the textview whereas I only want the name of the image to be shown example 123.jpg.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    BitmapFactory.Options options;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_SELECTED) {
        try {
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String s= getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
            imageName.append(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String mImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
            stream.close();
            //---orientation---
            try {
                int rotate = 0;
                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                            mImagePath);
                    dateTaken.append(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME));
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            rotate = 270;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            rotate = 180;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            rotate = 90;
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                yourSelectedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourSelectedImage , 0, 0, yourSelectedImage.getWidth(), yourSelectedImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
            //---end of orientation---

            imgButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imgButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image was not selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult - Portal");
}
```

Followed this link [Get filepath and filename of selected gallery image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324155/get-filepath-and-filename-of-selected-gallery-image-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a String operation.follwoing code will help you out.

```
    String path=":/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1414240995236.jpg";
   String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

possible duplicate of :
[How to get file name from file path in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570084/how-to-get-file-name-from-file-path-in-android)