# CLOSED - How do I import another class not in Java Library

Tags: java

I have this code in my java project, which reads a file and converts it into a string.

```
String txt = FileUtils.readFileToString(text);
```

It uses this class https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

How do I import this into my project?

Thanks :)

Comment: need to import 3rd party .jar file at you class path

Comment: If you have many dependencies - use maven/gradle. If you don't - download the jar and include it in your libraries using the class path.

Comment: may i know which editor are you using ? eclipse/netbean ?

Answer (score 2):

*If you are using Ant as a build in tool then below solution works,*

Step - 1:  download .jar file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonsiojar.htm),

Step - 2: Then after add it into your class path likewise,
Project right click -> properties

[image]

Step 3 : find Jar from you machine, and add it to  your class path. likewise,

[image]

Click -> OK.

Now, Your problem  has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are looking for deprecated method. I suggest you should not use deprecated methods if possible.

Secondly, if you just want to get content of file in `String`, you can do it in following way with [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and without using any third party library.

```
File file = new File("abc.txt");
String txt = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Include commons-io jar in build path of your project by downloading it from Apache site -

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: @vishalgajera  has provided you detail steps in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try following what Rene said here:
[Add commons-io dependency to gradle project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895557/add-commons-io-dependency-to-gradle-project-in-android-studio)

You can also try to drag the jar file under Jar folder of lib after downloading it, then right click on the Jar file and select the "Add as library" option. Then select your app from the dialog box.