# How to change decoration of a local HTML file to show it on the WebView in Android

Tags: android, html, css, webview

In my android application I used to open a local HTML file like the one below:

```
mPath = ... myHTML.html

webView.loadUrl("file:///" + mPath);
```

Now I want to make some changes in my HTML file such as font size, align from left to right and right to left and ... I guess that I can do that by adding a CSS file to head of my HTML, but the problem is I have no idea how to access the source of my HTML file and convert it to string.

Is there any better way to change the decoration of a local HTML file? if not, how can I access the source of my HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'm answering my own question. I used Panos's answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13357785/1572408

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

In `onCreate()`:

```
    File fl = new File(myLesson);
    FileInputStream fin;
    fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);

    ret = ret.replace("<body>","<body align='right' style='font-size:14pt;>");
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", ret, "text/html",
                "UTF-8", "");
```