# Android: read from text file and convert to string, added "dot" in first line

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I use below code for read txt file and convert to string

After convert, added dot to first line and i cant convert number string to integer

> Code :

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("db.txt");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str);
            }

            in.close();
            Log.i("error", "" + buf.toString().trim());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> Errorlog :

[image]

Comment: where is the dot?

Comment: you should check it this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13357785/5773037

Comment: The code to read a txt file seems fine. Maybe there is a dot at the beginning of your db.txt?

Comment: @cherry-wave no in db.txt not dot first of file

Comment: So I used your exact code to post a txt-file with random content and no extra dot was added at the beginning. Maybe you could post your db.txt file (just the first line?)