# How to convert bitmap image to file format which I get from canvas in android

Tags: android, file, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I make canvas view which I want to send in server using retrofit library. I get canvas view in bitmap format. Now I want to convert bitmap to file format so that I can upload in server in file format.

Comment: convert bitmap to base64 and upload it to server

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
file.createNewFile();

/* Convert bitmap to byte array */
Bitmap bitmap = bitmap; //bitmap is your bitmap file which you want to convert
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

/* write the bytes in file */
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Always close and flush the FileOutputStream.

Comment: FileOutputStream require string values

Comment: Read file as a string. for this visit the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910503/read-file-as-string

Answer (score 0):

Convert ua bitmap to base64 String like below and send it using string

```
 public static String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat  compressFormat, int quality)//u can pass 100 in quality or any integer

{
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```