# How I can get the UUID of an Android device by JNI

Tags: java, android, linux, java-native-interface

I am developing a dynamic library for Android devices by JNI. And I have to get the UUID of the device without using of the Android APIs. I have tried to get the CPU Serial Number or MAC Address via Shell Scrip. such as:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
```

But the Serial Number is always 0000000000000, And there is no wlan0 folder in my phone. Now I am so lost, can anybody give me some tips!

Comment: hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888055/include-uuid-h-into-androind-ndk-project

Comment: Thank you Viruss mca! I have got the UUID by the uuid library ,But i found the UUID is not what I want, I need a Unique Device ID to specify my device via, And I cant get it via Java! How can I do?