# How to get specific libraries from Android Open Source Project?

Tags: android, android-ndk

For my Android app, I need the source code for uuidlib that I would like to build as a static library and link with my native code. Another post [Include uuid.h into Android NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888055/include-uuid-h-into-androind-ndk-project) mentions that the source code is available in AOSP at external/e2fsprogs/lib/uuid/ directory.

I followed the instruction on AOSP page and did a "repo init" and a "repo sync." The synchronization is still going on for the past one hour.

I am wondering if there is a better way to obtain the source code for just the library I need and not download the entire 10G of repository on my machine.

If not, what do I need to do to get uuid after "repo sync" finishes? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a better way to obtain the source code for just the library I need and not download the entire 10G of repository on my machine.

Per [the repository instructions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/e2fsprogs/):

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/e2fsprogs
```

Comment: If the library has any dependencies in AOSP, you would need to identify and obtain these as well. That can be a time-consuming task if there are many dependencies – I decided to just fetch the whole thing overnight and not have to worry about missing a dependency of a dependency somewhere. YMMV.